# Divergence of $\sin(n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Using only the standard analytic properties of the sine function, but no particular definition of it,

what's a neat little proof that the sequence $\sin(n)$ diverges?

Comment: I still wonder why people call "divergent" sequences that do not have a limit. It is a bounded sequence, how we may dare to call it "divergent"?

Comment: Divergent = not convergent, by standard definition?

Comment: It is not a universal definition. More or less, [it is like](www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw) to call "closed" sets that are not "open". Not a very wise terminology choice.